# Copy Folder from remote to Gitlab runner to save it in Artifacts

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner, artifact

Is it possible to save reports inside a folder on a remote server with the Gitlab runner so that I can save it in Artifacts?

Comment: Am I right that you would like to upload Reports to the folder on a machine with the gitLab runner installed and later push that reports into GitLab as an Artifacts?

Comment: yess i wan't to copy a folder from a remote server into gitlab runner and pass it as an artifact  ( the folder contains html reports for exécuted tasks on the remote server) currently im using the runner log (raw) and filtring it :(

Answer (score 0):

> wan't to copy a folder from a remote server into gitlab runner and pass it as an artifact

I can see a few ways to achieve that:

1. create a job that will be fetching a folder from a remote server and upload it to GitLab as an Artifact.
2. create a folder on the server with the GitLab runner installed, fetch reports into that folder (scp/rsync, etc), and access it by GitLab runner itself (and GitLab Runner will save them as an Artifact).

Let me know if you need to know more, so I'll update my answer.