# Copy artifacts to gitlab runner container

Tags: docker, gitlab, playwright

I am running a container (within a VM) where my tests are executed. I have gitlab runner again configured to run as docker container in another VM. Once the tests are executed, I need the report to be uploaded as an artifact. I have tried couple of scenarios, but nothing works:

```yaml
fetch_report:
  stage: fetch_report
  script:
    - echo -e "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" > /tmp/$CI_PIPELINE_ID
    - echo $SSH_KEY >> /tmp/$CI_PIPELINE_ID
    - echo -e "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----" >> /tmp/$CI_PIPELINE_ID
    - chmod 600 /tmp/$CI_PIPELINE_ID
    - cat /tmp/$CI_PIPELINE_ID
    - mkdir -p $CI_PROJECT_DIR/playwright_report_$CI_PIPELINE_ID/
    - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
    - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
    - '[[ -f /.dockerenv ]] && export DOCKER_HOST="tcp://0.0.0.0:2375"'
    *- ssh -i /tmp/$CI_PIPELINE_ID -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -p 22 deploy@ip "docker cp be07e8ed7fc1:/usr/src/app/playwright-report/. $CI_PROJECT_DIR/playwright_report_$CI_PIPELINE_ID/"*
    *# - ssh -i /tmp/$CI_PIPELINE_ID -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -p 22 deploy@ip "docker cp be07e8ed7fc1:/usr/src/app/playwright-report/. /etc/playwright-reports/$CI_PIPELINE_ID/"*
    *#- ssh -i /tmp/$CI_PIPELINE_ID -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -p 22 deploy@ip "cp -r /etc/playwright-reports/1227774870/ ./"*
- ls -la ./playwright_report_$CI_PIPELINE_ID/
    artifacts:
      paths:
        - ./playwright_report_$CI_PIPELINE_ID/
    rules:
      - when: always
```

I am trying to copy the file directly from the test container to gitlab runner container using the first SSH script, but it fails with the error *invalid output path: directory "/builds/tenderd/qa/Quality-Assurance" does not exist*

Second and third are inter-dependent, where second works which copies the files to the local path where the test container runs. However, from the local path, copying again to the gitlab runner container fails.

I saw this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65438880/copy-folder-from-remote-to-gitlab-runner-to-save-it-in-artifacts), however not sure how it needs to be achieved (other than the way I did). Is there a way to get this resolved? Or any alternate approach for the same. Any guidance will be really appreciated.